# GNU Make: Ensure existence of prerequisite and disable implicit rule search

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

**Question:**

How can I disable implicit rule searches on a prerequisite while still ensuring that the prerequisite actually exists?

**Background:**

Consider the following initial `Makefile`:

```
b: a
    @echo MAKING B
    cp a b
```

`a` is a file which is required in order to make `b`. If the file `a` exists, `make b` runs successfully. If it doesn't exist, we obtain the following error:

```
make: *** No rule to make target `a', needed by `b'.  Stop.`
```

This is exactly what we expected, however on inspecting the output of `make --debug=a b`, we see that even when `a` exists, `make` is searching through pre-defined implicit rules fitting `a` in order to see whether it can be re-made. For example, if the file `a.c` happened to exist, then `make` would try to compile `a.c` to produce the file `a`. To prevent this, we define an explicit rule for `a` with an empty recipe. This gives us the updated `Makefile`:

```
a: ;

b: a
    @echo MAKING B
    cp a b
```

The problem now is that the recipe for `make b` runs even if `a` does not exist, which results in a failure. Is there any other way to indicate that `a` should exist, while not searching for implicit rules to build `a`? I would like to do this without giving a recipe for `a` which checks its existence.

Comment: Would this be sufficient for you? `a: ; [ -f $@ ]  # a should exist` I.e. fail `make b` with a mild hint. I've tried few ways to suppress implicit pattern rules or override them for a with static patter, but I'd then end up seeing same thing as your empty `a`, i.e. it'd just dive into making `b` without `a` being present.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. That would certainly work, but I would like to know whether this is possible without defining a recipe to check for the target's existence. I put this clarification at the end. I feel like this should be possible without any explicit commands.

Comment: Not sure if this would not mess with the rest of your `Makefile`, but to get desired behavior for this specific case, you could run make with `-r` or add empty `.SUFFIXES:` to your `Makefile`. Is that acceptable? Or too far reaching?

Comment: I don't fully understand how `.SUFFIXES` would work, but `-r` is too far reaching. I might want to retain built-in rules for other targets.

Comment: I had a look into `.SUFFIXES` and would similarly like to keep it as it is. Let's say I did set `.SUFFIXES` to empty or used `-r`, I might still have defined an implicit rule myself whose target matches `a` and which in this case I would not want to match.

Comment: Would you in any case like to add your initial suggestion as an answer? If we conclude that this is otherwise impossible, I can accept that as an answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'll try to sum up state of our discussion so far. Perhaps someone still pop's up with another/better insight.

Besides the option also mentioned in the question itself (see bellow for explainer on latest iteration for this approach):

```
a:
        $(error missing file "$@")
b: a
        @echo MAKING B
        cp a b
```

In theory it should be possible to disable implicit pattern rule altogether or for specific (set) of target(s) by either [defining a no recipe target rule](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Canceling-Rules.html#Canceling-Rules) (`% : %.c`) or [defining](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Static-Usage.html#Static-Usage) a [static pattern rule](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Static-versus-Implicit.html#Static-versus-Implicit) (`a: % : %.c`). Nonetheless the resulting behavior, in case there is an `a.c` file, seems to be the same as with an empty rule for `a:`. I.e. `make b` just proceeds without file `a` being present (and we'd later fail trying to access it).

Since at least some of the implicit rule seem to be implemented as [suffix rules](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Suffix-Rules.html#Suffix-Rules), it's possible to disable consideration of inputs like `a.c` by purging list of default suffices:

```
.SUFFIXES:
```

Or inhibit use of implicit built-in rules altogether by invoking make with `-r` (or `--no-builtin-rules`) option. These however are rather heavy handed as they impact processing of all the rules across the `Makefile`.

---

To work the comment in:

as mentioned disabling couple of the built in rules for C compilation would appear to yield the desired result, namely:

```
% : %.c
% : %.o
```

Would result with `a.c` present and no `a` in `make: *** No rule to make target 'a', needed by 'b'.  Stop.`

However (like -r) it's rather intrusive as in all other targets relying on the implicit rule would be impacted. While at the same time it's not as very far reaching, because it does not cover other cases like `a.C`, `a.cpp`, `a,v`,...

Static rule should be able to replace pattern rules where applicable (a more specific rule being applied over the more generic one when matching). But indeed limiting its to a single target does basically put it on par with just a specific `a:` rule.

I am actually not sure what the rest of the tree looks like and what all possible build steps could occur. With current understanding I would still gravitate to explicit target with file existence check should files with colliding names be a possibility and concern.

---

*Explanation for the latest version of simple failing rule:*

As [@Stein](https://stackoverflow.com/users/106275/stein) followed up on the topic, he actually very helpfully pointed out: Simple (always) failing rule for "building" `a` is perfectly sufficient. If a file of that name (`a`) exists, the rule for target `a` never gets to run its recipe. For the case the file is not there, we can just have a recipe that fails with an error message.

Comment: The rule `%: %.o` would also need to be disabled alongside `%: %.c`. Also, a built-in implicit rule of the form `X: Y; recipe` can be overridden only by another rule of the form `X: Y...`, where `...` may either be the empty string or a recipe. This means that the static rule `a: %: %.c`, which does indeed match with `X: Y`, does not in fact override it. In addition, I believe that the static rule `a: %: %.c` is in any case equivalent to the rule `a: a.c`. What are your thoughts on this?

Comment: I think you'd better mention `$(wildcard $@)` instead of `$(file < $@)` there, because the latter would not work if the file is genuinely empty, and probably not work well if the contents are huge.

Comment: @Stein: Thanks for the hint. I've updated the example as suggested. It actually still yielded expected result with genuinely empty (0B length) file, but it would indeed read the file regardless of its size. [`wildcard`](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Wildcard-Function.html#Wildcard-Function) behaves as needed with omission of non-matching pattern(s) and does not have the same unwanted side effects.

Comment: I had a hard time figuring it why it yields expected results. 1. The file was never read. The `$(if` is pointless: if file a exists, then the recipe will not be executed at all. The recipe can simply unconditionally error out. If file a had prerequisites (and not just order-only-prerequisites), then the `$(if` would be useful to express that it needs to be updated rather than created. 2. Several contemporary Linux distributions feature GNU Make 4.1 which knows `$(file >` but barks `"*** Invalid file operation: < a"` at `$(file <`. I built 4.2 myself to get it to work.

Comment: @Stein: thanks a bunch for following up on that. I have to admit to have dropped the ball on digging deeper once the setup seemed to have worked (make 4.2.1 on slack-current in my case). Totally my bad. I've update the answer with your findings. I can also turn it into a community wiki entry if you just wanted to have a go at it?

Comment: @OndrejK. thanks for motivating me to find out what community wiki is, but I think the question is well covered now.